# Trying to convert Apex to be used in an Aura Component Form

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am new to Aura Components, and I'm having a hard time trying to move them over from using Visualforce Pages and Apex.  I am getting the following error:

> Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context: System.PageReference ZZ_C360ConsIntCreateController_Working.save()

This is understandable as I'm trying to pass a Public method to a static method.  Is there a way to pass the following public method:

```
// Referenced by public static @AuraEnabled method
public PageReference save() {
    PageReference pr;
    if (validateForm()) {
        if (!isEdit) {
            i.ContactDate = DateTime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
            i.Page_x = 1;
        }
        else {
            if(!i.ContactDate.endsWith(' 00:00:00'))
                i.ContactDate += ' 00:00:00';
        }

        i.Warning = warning ? 'Y' : 'N';
        if (String.isNotBlank(i.WarningExpirationDate)) {
            system.debug('warnexp before: ' + i.WarningExpirationDate);
            i.WarningExpirationDate = ECCUtil.JavaDateStringToDate(i.WarningExpirationDate).formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd');
            system.debug('warnexp after: ' + i.WarningExpirationDate);
        }
        
        listValuesForCompare(after);

        system.debug('C360ConsIntCreateController.save: relId: ' 
            + relId + ', consId: ' + consId + ', ContactDate: ' + i.ContactDate
            + ', ContactSeq: ' + i.ContactSeq + ', Page_x: ' + i.Page_x);
        if (isEdit) {
            system.debug('editing');
            try {
                //adding ability to edit
                if(vipCheck || gpCheck){
                    if(hasViewLongComments){
                    }
                    else{
                        System.debug('hasViewLongComments = ' + hasViewLongComments);
                        System.debug('vipCheck during save = ' + vipCheck);
                        System.debug('gpCheck during save = ' + gpCheck);
                        System.debug('i.LongComments = ' + i.LongComments);
                        String existingComment = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('comments');
                        System.debug('existingComment = ' + existingComment);
                        String addedComment = i.LongComments;
                        System.debug('addedComment = ' + addedComment);
                        i.LongComments = (existingComment + ' ' + addedComment);
                        System.debug('i.LongComments = ' + i.LongComments);
                    }
                }
                system.debug('consId = ' + consId);
                system.debug('i = ' + i);
                system.debug('i.LongComments = ' + i.LongComments);
                C360Util.editInteraction(consId, i);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                if(!hasViewLongComments){
                    i.LongComments = null;
                }
                system.debug('C360ConsIntCreateController.save: editInteraction exception: ' + e.getMessage());
                ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'There was an error saving your interaction.'));
                return null;
            }

            ECCUtil.createTask(ci, 'Interaction Edited', 'Completed', consId, 
                before, 
                after);
        }
        else {
            system.debug('creating');
            i.WarningExpirationDate = null;  //forcing null for now.  Any value other than null throws a c360 error --Kris K
            system.debug(
              'i.ContactDate = ' + i.ContactDate + 
              '\ni.Page_x = ' + i.Page_x + 
              '\ni.ContactCategory = ' + i.ContactCategory + 
              '\ni.ContactType = ' + i.ContactType +
              '\ni.TransactionSource.Technique = ' + i.TransactionSource.Technique + 
              '\ni.ResponseCategory = ' + i.ResponseCategory + 
              '\ni.ResponseType = ' + i.ResponseType + 
              '\ni.Warning = ' + i.Warning + 
              '\ni.WarningExpirationDate = ' + i.WarningExpirationDate + 
              '\ni.LongComments = ' + i.LongComments
            );
            try {
                System.debug('i = ' + i);
                System.debug('i.Technique = ' + i.Technique);
                C360Util.createInteraction(consId, i);
            }
            catch(CalloutException e) {
                C360Util.createInteractionDMS(consId, i);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                system.debug('C360ConsIntCreateController.save: createInteraction exception: ' + e.getMessage());
                ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'There was an error saving your interaction.'));
                return null;
            }

            ECCUtil.createTask(ci, 'Interaction Created', 'Completed', consId, 
                before, 
                after);
        }

        pr = new PageReference('/Apex/C360Interactions');
        pr.getParameters().put('id', relId);
    }
    return pr;
}

private boolean validateForm() {
    boolean valid = true;

    if(String.isBlank(i.ContactCategory)) {
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Contact Category is required.'));
        valid = false;
    }
    if(String.isBlank(i.ContactType)) {
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Contact Type is required.'));
        valid = false;
    }
    if(String.isBlank(i.ResponseType) && String.isNotBlank(i.ResponseCategory)) {
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Response Type is required if Response Category is         vided.'));
        valid = false;
    }
    if(String.isBlank(i.ResponseCategory) && String.isNotBlank(i.ResponseType)) {
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Response Category is required if Response Type is provided.'));
        valid = false;
    }
    if(String.isBlank(i.TransactionSource.Technique)) {
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Contact method is required.'));
        valid = false;
    }
    if(warning && String.isBlank(i.LongComments)) {
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Comments are required on a warning.'));
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

into a static method?  I attempted something really simple, but, understandably, it came back with an error:

> Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context: System.PageReference ZZ_C360ConsIntCreateController_Working.save()

```
// Aura Component Methods
public static void auraSave() {
    save();
}
```

I know that Static methods cannot necessarily pull from nonstatic methods.  But, is there a way use this or translate it more simply that wouldn't require me to rewrite the entire apex controller?  The other methods used are listed below:

```
private boolean validateForm() {
    boolean valid = true;

    if(String.isBlank(i.ContactCategory)) {
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Contact Category is required.'));
        valid = false;
    }
    if(String.isBlank(i.ContactType)) {
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Contact Type is required.'));
        valid = false;
    }
    if(String.isBlank(i.ResponseType) && String.isNotBlank(i.ResponseCategory)) {
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Response Type is required if Response Category is         vided.'));
        valid = false;
    }
    if(String.isBlank(i.ResponseCategory) && String.isNotBlank(i.ResponseType)) {
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Response Category is required if Response Type is provided.'));
        valid = false;
    }
    if(String.isBlank(i.TransactionSource.Technique)) {
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Contact method is required.'));
        valid = false;
    }
    if(warning && String.isBlank(i.LongComments)) {
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Comments are required on a warning.'));
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

and

```
public void listValuesForCompare(List<String> vals) {
    vals.add(String.format('{0} = {1}', new String[] {'ContactDate', i.ContactDate == null ? '' : i.ContactDate}));
    vals.add(String.format('{0} = {1}', new String[] {'Page', i.Page_x == null ? '' : String.valueOf(i.Page_x)}));
    vals.add(String.format('{0} = {1}', new String[] {'Contact Category', i.ContactCategory == null ? '' : i.ContactCategory}));
    vals.add(String.format('{0} = {1}', new String[] {'Contact Type', i.ContactType == null ? '' : i.ContactType}));
    vals.add(String.format('{0} = {1}', new String[] {'Contact Method', i.TransactionSource.Technique == null ? '' : i.TransactionSource.Technique}));
    vals.add(String.format('{0} = {1}', new String[] {'Response Category', i.ResponseCategory == null ? '' : i.ResponseCategory}));
    vals.add(String.format('{0} = {1}', new String[] {'Response Type', i.ResponseType == null ? '' : i.ResponseType}));
    vals.add(String.format('{0} = {1}', new String[] {'Warning', i.Warning == null ? '' : i.Warning}));
    vals.add(String.format('{0} = {1}', new String[] {'Warning Expiration Date', i.WarningExpirationDate == null ? '' : i.WarningExpirationDate}));
}    public void listValuesForCompare(List<String> vals) {
    vals.add(String.format('{0} = {1}', new String[] {'ContactDate', i.ContactDate == null ? '' : i.ContactDate}));
    vals.add(String.format('{0} = {1}', new String[] {'Page', i.Page_x == null ? '' : String.valueOf(i.Page_x)}));
    vals.add(String.format('{0} = {1}', new String[] {'Contact Category', i.ContactCategory == null ? '' : i.ContactCategory}));
    vals.add(String.format('{0} = {1}', new String[] {'Contact Type', i.ContactType == null ? '' : i.ContactType}));
    vals.add(String.format('{0} = {1}', new String[] {'Contact Method', i.TransactionSource.Technique == null ? '' : i.TransactionSource.Technique}));
    vals.add(String.format('{0} = {1}', new String[] {'Response Category', i.ResponseCategory == null ? '' : i.ResponseCategory}));
    vals.add(String.format('{0} = {1}', new String[] {'Response Type', i.ResponseType == null ? '' : i.ResponseType}));
    vals.add(String.format('{0} = {1}', new String[] {'Warning', i.Warning == null ? '' : i.Warning}));
    vals.add(String.format('{0} = {1}', new String[] {'Warning Expiration Date', i.WarningExpirationDate == null ? '' : i.WarningExpirationDate}));
}
```